# Find the value of the limit using l'Hôpital's Rule

Tags: calculus

What is $$\lim_{x \to 1^-} \frac{\ln(2x)}{\ln(x)}?$$ I tried evaluating and I got $\frac{2}{1}$ but I know it's wrong.

Comment: Why L'Hospital? The top is perfectly respectable near $1$.

Comment: The answer is -infinity but I'm not sure how to get there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One should not disturb the poor Marquis, he is busy enough with problems for which the Rule he bought from Bernoulli is relevant.

The top is perfectly respectable near $1$, it approaches $\ln 2$. The bottom approaches $0$ through negative values.

Now it is a matter of taste. Some people would say that the limit as $x\to 0^-$ does not exist. Some would say it is $-\infty$.

Comment: I think you meant "the poor Guillaume François Antoine."

Comment: I liked your statement "Now it is a matter of taste. Some people would say that the limit as $x \to 0^{-}$ does not exist. Some would say it is $-\infty$." and this makes the answer as unambiguous as possible.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\log 2x}{\log x}=\frac{\log 2+\log x}{\log x}\xrightarrow[x\to 1^-]{}-\infty$$